# doing a while loop in node.js, always give me the last array item?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, zombie.js

im using the zombie.js library , to do some testing for the dom, i have this script

```
Browser = require "zombie"
arr = new Array("http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://msn.com")
i = 0
while i < arr.length
    b = new Browser()
    b.visit arr[i], ->
        console.log b.text "title"
    b.close()
    i++
```

everything works, but it only logs the msn title two times, so the while loop is logging the last item in the array twice. i can't seem to see what the problem is?

Comment: Why are you using `while` loop as `for` instead of using `for(var i = 0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){...}`

Comment: im actually using for instead `while`, thanks for pointing that out?

Comment: plus you can't use for in coffeescript, you can use for items in arr ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're registering a callback for when the browser's `visit` has completed. By that time, the loop has run to completion, so the variable `b` points to the last browser you created, which means its title will be that of MSN, not those of the other pages. In order to fix this, use a closure:

```
Browser = require "zombie"
arr = new Array("http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://msn.com")
i = 0
createBrowser = (url) ->
    b = new Browser()
    b.visit url, -> console.log b.text "title"
    b.close()

while i < arr.length
    createBrowser(arr[i++])
```

This works because now there is a separate scope for each browser you create, and a separate browser variable.

Alternatively, use the callback arguments for ZombieJS's `visit` function:

```
Browser = require "zombie"
arr = new Array("http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://msn.com")
i = 0
while i < arr.length
    b = new Browser()
    b.visit arr[i], (e, myBrowser) ->
        console.log myBrowser.text "title"
    b.close()
    i++
```

Comment: There's also the `do` keyword for these situations, look at the end of the [Loops and Comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) section of the manual.

Answer (score 1):

The `visit` method is asynchronous, taking a callback function. In the other words, `visit` is called three times before any logging happens, i.e. console.log is *not* executed between `b.visit` and `b.close` calls. By the time the last callback finishes, `b` refers to "last" Browser instance (the msn one). The `visit` method likely passes the result for the callback, please check the documentation.

```
Browser = require 'zombie'

for url in ["foo", "bar", "baz"] # elegant way to loop lists in coffeescript
  b = new Browser
  b.visit url, (err, b) ->       # b given as argument masks the b in outer scope
    console.log b.text "title"
    b.close()
```

Comment: yes thanks, so how can i run asynchronous function in a loop, is thier a solution for that, sorry kinda new to this async stuff ?

Comment: The callback function for visit takes two arguments, error and browser, e.g. visit arr[i], (err, browser) -> browser.text "title"

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is something like the following (warning, untested!):

```
Browser = require "zombie"
sites = ['http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com', 'http://msn.com']

process = (site) ->
  b = new Browser()
  b.visit site, () ->
    title = b.text title
    console.log title
    b.close()

process site for site in sites
```

I've taken the liberty of changing a few bits and pieces - hopefully it's still clear.

JavaScript (and CoffeeScript) have strange scoping rules if you aren't used to them. I find it's usually best to do all work in a function to make things work as you expect.

I don't know exactly how zombie.js works, but I think this should do as you expect.